# Correlate string with array of strings

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

On a music database, I've got a costumers table in the following form:

```
costumer_id | category_a | category_b | category_c  ... etc.
```

Each of the categories, consists of other sub-categories. For example, category_a could be "rock", which consists of the following sub-categories: "hard_rock", "rock_n_roll", "progressive_rock" etc. The record on the table holds only the main category string though, "rock".

While reading each record I'm interested in, with a DataReader I need a practical way to correlate the main category, hold on the reader with it's sub-categories for further processing. Any ideas?

Comment: How much data are we talking about?  1000's of rows?  Can you read the entire data set into a DataTable and do some post-processing with the data you need?

Comment: The costumers table is small, we got around 100 costumers. I could but I would still need a way to correlate the main with the sub-categories, wouldn't I ?

Comment: Can you explain how you would do this correlation if you had to work with the data manually?  Then we can think about converting that algorithm into code.

Comment: I'm basically writing a WCF file transfer service. The subcategories represent folders on the HDD and from a service operation I'm returning to the client the main categories he is using. On the client side, I need somehow to convert the main categories to sub-categories i.e folder paths on the server, so that the client can request files from those server folders.

Comment: This is a horrible database design.  Just read all the columns for a given row.  This sentence does not make sense: "The record on the table holds only the main category string though, "rock"."  Considering you just done saying that `category_a` contains "hard_rock", "rock_n_roll", and "progressive_rock" I assume seperated by a character.

Comment: I know, you can tell that to my boss about the database design.
Sorry for the bad description. That table I'm reading knows nothing about sub-categories. Just main categories of music which consist of multiple folders on the server. What I need is to somehow convert the main category string returned to the client, to an array of strings/subcategories/folders on the server.

Comment: Why would you want a Attribute like category set the storage location of a file. What if you changed the category? What if something fit it to more than one subcategory? Also as others have mentioned you can't get a subcateogry from category. For example if I say an animal is a reptile how are you supposed to know its an alligator and not a boa constrictor?

Comment: @ConradFrix this is how the system was designed. Not my design btw. We also can't change much about categories, that would break existing clients. I can do this with if, else if statements on the client but I was looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: @Pantelis Ok well you might want to consider editing your question to include a sample of the if-else statements that you could use but don't want to.